# Using file_field element with Cheezy Page Objects and Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, element, page-object-gem

I'm trying to use the file_field element inside a page object with no success.

I have and HTML page with:

```
<input class="stuff" name="imagebtn" type="button" value="Upload Image" style="display: inline-block;">
```

And a page object like:

```
class CreateProductStep2Page
  include PageObject
  page_url NavigationHelpers::get_path 'upload_product'
  file_field(:upload_image_0, :name =>'imagebtn')

  def upload_image
    puts "debug image-element: " + upload_image_0_element.to_s
    self.upload_image_0 = '/home/user/RubymineProjects/Cucumber/test_data/image.png'
    self.upload_image_0_element.click

    sleep 100
  end
end
```

When I execute the code, the debug print shows that the element is defined and is a file_field. But it does not upload the picture (it opens the file browser window - always in the Downloads folder) but does nothing else.
What should I change to upload the image?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Did you try specifying a file? The code looks like it is just trying to select a folder.

Comment: Ups, it was a typo while writing it down here. I've already edited the question, and, yes, I do have the file specified, and the file exists in that folder.

Comment: What are you trying to do when you click the upload_image_0_element? I don't believe there's any reason to do it, and I suspect it might be the problem.

Comment: Johnson, it's a file button to upload a file to the server, that is also displayed in a <img>.